# Ubuntu 16 w/PHP7, Graphics Magick: Class 'GMagick' not found

Tags: 16.04, graphics, php7

I just set up my production server on Ubuntu 16 and PHP7/Apache. I have installed the Graphics Magick package locally using

```
brew install php56-gmagick
```

Doing that installs graphics magick as well as the php module so it is accessible using the GMagick php class.

On the server I can install graphics magick using

```
sudo apt-get install graphicsmagick
```

The package was installed successfully but does not include a PHP helper class.

Does anyone out there know if there is a package to take care of installing that?

Also, I was able to get Imagick installed and working with php using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install php-imagick
```

I am interested in comparing the performance of the two to see which is lighter on the server.

I am looking here:

```
http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/php/
http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/graphics/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install Pear so you can use pecl

```
sudo apt install php-pear
```

Install phpize which is require by gmagick

```
sudo apt install php7.0-dev graphicsmagick libgraphicsmagick1-dev
```

This installs the PHP extension:

```
sudo pecl install gmagick-2.0.4RC1
```

This loads the extension in the php.ini

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "extension=gmagick.so" >>  /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini'
```

Restart Apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, I guess all I would need to do is change to ``` /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini  ``` also how to install pecl?

Comment: Fixed! PECL is part of php-pear.

Comment: Almost there, thank you for making that update and explaing PECL PEAR relationship. running: phpize
sh: 1: phpize: not found
ERROR: `phpize' failed

Comment: sudo apt-get install php7.0-dev

Comment: Just as a note, I noticed with Brew you installed PHP 5.6's gmagick. I would warn against using brew at all on Ubuntu systems. It's wayyy easier to use Launchpad and Apt imho.

Comment: ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/gmagick/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config --with-gmagick' failed

Comment: Used brew for my macbook local install

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46824/discussion-between-matt-o-and-zeros-and-ones).

Comment: Try sudo apt install libgraphicsmagick1-dev (per [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626558/please-provide-the-prefix-of-graphicsmagick-installation-autodetect))

Comment: Ok that worked, no errors reload apache after running, sudo 'echo "extension=gmagick.so" >>  /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini'. Still saying Class 'GMagick' not found

Comment: Working! the command sudo 'echo "extension=gmagick.so" >> /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini', did not work I had to manually add it to that file

Comment: do you think both of these are needed ? graphicsmagick libgraphicsmagick1-dev

Comment: Yes, the dev package makes the config available in /usr/bin, hence the `ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/gmagick/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config --with-gmagick` error

Answer (score 2):

Since there's now an Imagick package for PHP 7.0, you can do the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php-imagick graphicsmagick
sudo service apache2 reload
```

To test, run:

```
$ php -i |grep imagick
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-imagick.ini,
imagick
imagick module => enabled
imagick module version => 3.4.0RC6
imagick classes => Imagick, ImagickDraw, ImagickPixel, ImagickPixelIterator, ImagickKernel
imagick.locale_fix => 0 => 0
imagick.progress_monitor => 0 => 0
imagick.skip_version_check => 0 => 0
```