# Ubuntu 16 w/PHP7, Graphics Magick: Class 'GMagick' not found

Tags: php

I just set up my production server on Ubuntu 16 and PHP7/Apache. I have installed the Graphics Magick package locally using

```
brew install php56-gmagick
```

Doing that installs graphics magick as well as the php module so it is accessible using the GMagick php class.

On the server I can install graphics magick using

```
sudo apt-get install graphicsmagick
```

The package was installed successfully but does not include a PHP helper class.

Does anyone out there know if there is a package to take care of installing that?

Also, I was able to get Imagick installed and working with php using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install php-imagick
```

I am interested in comparing the performance of the two to see which is lighter on the server.

I am looking here:

```
http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/php/
http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/graphics/
```

Comment: This has been answered already in this thread: http://askubuntu.com/questions/837142/ubuntu-16-w-php7-graphics-magick-class-gmagick-not-found/837161?noredirect=1#837161